# Apache Mina Core Incompatible Class Change Error

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java-based FTP server that I can embed in another project.  I'm using the Apache mina libraries for the FTP Server.  I can start the server but when I try to connect to it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java. lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.register(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:276)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.addLast(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:175)
at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder.buildFilterChain(DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder.java:452)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:430)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:412)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$200(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:56)
at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:885)
at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:51)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've done some reading on the cause of the error. [This site](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-how-to-resolve-incompatible-class-change-error/) at least implies it's an issue with the Apache Mina code.

I'm using Apache Mina Core Libraries **v2.019** and Apache FTP libraries **v1.1.1**, both are the latest that I can find

Here is my server implementation:

```
public FTPServer(final String ipadress, final int port){   
    FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
    ListenerFactory listenerfactory = new ListenerFactory();

    listenerfactory.setDataConnectionConfiguration( 
        new DataConnectionConfigurationFactory().createDataConnectionConfiguration()
    );

    ConnectionConfigFactory connection = new ConnectionConfigFactory();
    connection.setMaxLoginFailures(10);
    connection.setLoginFailureDelay(5);
    connection.setAnonymousLoginEnabled(false);

    // set the ip address of the listener
    listenerfactory.setServerAddress(ipaddress);

    // set the port of the listener
    if (port == 0){
        listenerfactory.setPort(PORT);
    }
    else {
        listenerfactory.setPort(port);
        // replace the default listener
        serverFactory.addListener("default", listenerfactory.createListener());

serverFactory.setConnectionConfig(connection.createConnectionConfig());
    }

    PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new 
    PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
    userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("myusers.properties"));
    userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());
    UserManager um = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
    BaseUser user = new BaseUser();

    user.setName("test");
    user.setPassword("test");
    user.setHomeDirectory("");

    try {
      um.save(user);
    } catch (FtpException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        this.stopServer();
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    serverFactory.setUserManager(um);
    server = serverFactory.createServer();
    //this.StartServer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started at the beginning and used the Apache sample code to create an FTP server. I stuck it in a static method in Main.java and removed the references to my server code.  I was unable to reproduce my error.  I then copied bits of my code to the new static method until I had the equivalent to my original code, and was unable to reproduce the original failure.  I then restored my code to Main.java and removed the call to the static method.  I still couldn't reproduce the error.  I'm assuming this was some sort of issue with NetBeans that persisted across several clean and build but was fixed when I brought in the new Apache sample code.